# Can we short JFET source and gate junctions as shown in the circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, power-electronics, jfet

Is the below circuit accurate?

[image]

The way the circuit is drawn in the question it looks like the source current is entering the gate, which is not possible since ig = 0 (excluding very low leakage).
Also, how the source current would return to the drain to be a close or complete circuit in the way it's drawn in the question there is no ground nor a return path from the source back to the drain right?

In my humble opinion I suspect it's as I draw it below:
[image]

Comment: Correct. Top schematic is an open circuit. SOmething isn't right there.

Comment: I also agree with your schematic. Maybe the author forgot to put the ground node at the bottom. Otherwise, the gate and source would be floating nodes.

Comment: @DKNguyen also, an ideal current source would always produce the same value regardless of any changes in the transistor mode. I think it should have been voltage source, which is the norm.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, the drain current is the same as the source current and there is no gate current except for a very low level of leakage.
- The bottom of Rs should be connected to circuit common (ground).
- The drain supply should be a voltage, not a current source.
- With an ideal current source the current will always be 7.5mA regardless of the value of Rx or anything else.

More here: https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/can-we-short-jfet-source-and-gate-junctions-as-shown-in-the-circuit.175900/